# How to draw the next region?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

the region is described in polar coordinates
$$D= (r,\theta): \begin{cases}
0\leq r \leq 2\sec(\theta) \\ -\frac{\pi}{4}\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4} \end{cases}$$  and the exercise asks to draw it on the $xy$ plane.

I attach a picture of how I drew it

[image]

the truth i'm not sure if that's okay.

Comment: It is a classical trick. Remember that $r \cos(\theta) = x$

Comment: http://fooplot.com/?lang=es#W3sidHlwZSI6MSwiZXEiOiIyc2VjKHRoZXRhKSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwODBjYyIsInRoZXRhbWluIjoiMCIsInRoZXRhbWF4IjoiMnBpIiwidGhldGFzdGVwIjoiLjAxIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwfV0-

Comment: You plotted an $r\theta$ graph, not an $xy$ graph.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each angle $\theta$ between $-\pi/4$ and $\pi/4$, the value of $r$ lies between $0$ and $2\sec \theta$.  That's literally what the inequalities state.  So if we pick a representative angle $\theta$ and draw a line from the origin with this angle, then stop when the line has length $2 \sec \theta$, where does it stop?  Call this endpoint $(x,y)$.

Well, if we drop a perpendicular to the $x$-axis from the endpoint, then we form a right triangle whose hypotenuse has length $r = 2 \sec \theta$, and $$\cos \theta = \frac{x}{r} = \frac{x}{2\sec \theta}, \\ \sin \theta = \frac{y}{r} = \frac{y}{2 \sec \theta}.$$  Therefore, the $x$-value of this coordinate is $$x = 2 \sec \theta \cos \theta = 2,$$ and the $y$-value of this coordinate is $$2 \sec \theta \sin \theta = 2 \tan \theta.$$  So $$(x,y) = (2, 2\tan \theta)$$ for each $\theta \in [-\pi/4, \pi/4]$.  Notice that because the $x$-value is always $2$, and $\tan (-\pi/4) = -1$ and $\tan \pi/4 = 1$, the set of all endpoints of these radial line segments is the line segment that connects $(2,-2)$ and $(2,2)$.  So the region that is enclosed by the given inequalities is a triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(2,-2)$, and $(2,2)$.  This region is swept by a radial line segment from the origin with angle ranging from $-\pi/4$ to $\pi/4$, and endpoint on the line $x = 2$.

Comment: thanks i could understand it very well!

Answer (score 0):

$r = 2\sec \theta\\
r\cos \theta = 2\\
x = r\cos \theta\\
x = 2$

This is a vertical line.

$\theta = \pm \frac {\pi}{4}$ gives the endpoints of the line.

$(2,-2), (2,2)$

But we have an inequality.  $r \le 2\sec \theta$

This means that we include everything between our line segment and the origin.

Or we have a isosceles right triangle.